# Trigger cell onClick instead of row onClick in React Table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

[I have the following table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuGUa.png)

I want that clicking on the three dots on the right side of the row will open a 
pop up menu, so I wrote an onClick function for this cell.

I also want that clicking on any other area in the row will redirect to another page, so i override the onClick of react table, (as suggested in the react table documentation: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6#custom-props)
in the following way:

```
 _getTdProps = (state, rowInfo, column, instance) => ({
     onClick: (e, handleOriginal) => {
        if (this.props.onTableRowClick) {
            this.props.onTableRowClick({ e, column, rowInfo, instance });
        }
        if (this.props.shouldHandleOriginalOnClick && handleOriginal) {
           handleOriginal();
        }
    },
})
```

My problem is that the redirection to another page occurs also when I pressing the three dots icon, instead of opening the popup menu.

How can I make this functionality works?
I've tried to play with z-index for cell and row but it didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call the `stopPropagation` method on the dots click event so that the event will not bubble up to the row when you click the dots.

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
handleKeyDown(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Let's stop this event.
  event.stopPropagation(); // This will work.
}
```